Step-by-step guide for packing CodeMirror 6 for WebExtension use
I have been using CodeMirror 5 in a browser WebExtension as JavaScript & CSS editor.
I am a novice (zero experience) in packing npm for WebExtension use.
Can you explain a step-by-step guide for packing CodeMirror 6 plus ESlint & Stylelint?
